# how to have one decimal point for numbers using angularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i've seen a few things for regExp but for some reason i'm thinking this should be more simple. Maybe not. Maybe regExp fits this perfectly and i don't understand the concept. Which, i do not. I don't understand regExp and thats why i haven't used it.

but what i am trying to do is build a basic calculator using AngularJS. My calculator has an ng-disable feature for my equals sign. So its not allowed to be pressed and won't work until a leftOperand, operator, and rightOperand are clicked. 
Now i don't want to disable the decimal when its clicked, because i might need it for my rightOperand.

But in essence i want my code to reflect "if there is an operator, then the rightOperand is rightOperand + any other Operand entered. Otherwise, the leftOperand is going to equal the leftOperand + any other Operand Entered. (which this is currently working ex. 333 + 45948594 works. The decimal works too. But! it can allow 333.464.6454 and i don't want that).

Trying to implement:
Also/And/Or/If a decimal is put into the leftOperand, then no other decimals are allowed for the leftOperand. If the rightOperand has a decimal, then no other decimals are allowed for the rightOperand.

what is the simplest way to go about this?

https://codepen.io/tevon/pen/Moewba

this is my setDecimal method, but its allowing more than 1 decimal for both the right and left operands

```
$scope.setDecimal = function (decimalEntered) {
        if ($scope.operator){
            $scope.rightOperand += decimalEntered;
        };
        else {$scope.leftOperand += decimalEntered;
        };
```

i was givin something like this: if string.indexOf('.') > -1  // then do something
but honestly, i'm not sure how to about the 'do something' part works, nor the -1 portion

not using Jquery.

Answer (score 1):

So you're building your operand as a string.  That means you can test the operand you currently have on your scope to see if it has a point using .indexOf.

if (myVariable.indexOf('.') === -1) myVariable += '.';

Answer (score 0):

You were right when you thought about indexOf - you just need to stop execution of this method if there's already dot there - and easiest way is `return`

```
if ($scope.rightOperand.indexOf('.')>-1) return;
```

[LINK](https://codepen.io/mackie_pl/pen/GEqLgZ)

Comment: well, that was a hint from @jsdevel, i take no cred for that

Comment: i don't get the -1 piece of it

Comment: Please refer to [indexOf secription](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof.asp) - ">-1" means that string given in parameter is found - means that dot is already there.